# SQL table copy script

Tags: php, mysql

I have a website http://www.league.vivahosting.co.uk which uses Joomla for main cms and Dragonflycms as the league component module.

Now what i want to achieve is a script to copy username and email from the `jos_users` table and insert it into the `cmsdf_users` table now the rows in each table are as follows

```
jos_users - username, email
cmsdf_users - username, user-email
```

now i'dlike to do the same with the passwords but joomal's encryption is hash:salted i believe and Dragonflycms is md5 so i'm thinking a workaround using a custom field provided by joomla to have a plain txt password that is encrypted during the transfer process  from db to db.

Now the custom field is not kept in the jos_users table its located in `letnp_user` which i believe are linked by `user_id`.

Below is what i have so far

```
<?php

// Set the connection information
print $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "DBName", "Pass");

// Select the original database containing old records
print mysql_select_db("DBName", $con);

// Check the connection
if (!$con)
{
print die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

// Select the records from the database
print $query = "SELECT * FROM letnp_users" or die(mysql_error());

// Run the query
print $result = mysql_query($query);

// Now select the new database
# mysql_select_db("cmsdf_users", $con);

// Loop through each row from the old database
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
     // Set each column to a variable
    $username = $row['username'];
    echo  $username;    
    $email = $row['email'];
    echo $email;
     // You could also reset defaults or check for NULL columns
     // Here's an example for permissions:
     if ($row['permissions'] == 0)
     {
          $permissions = 1;
     }
     else if ($row['permissions'] > 3)
     {
          $permissions = $row['permissions'] + 1;
     }
     else
     {
          $permissions = $row['permissions'];
     }
     $date = $row['date'];

     // Set up the INSERT query
     $insert = "INSERT INTO cmsdf_users (username, user_email) VALUES ('$username', '$user_email')";


     // Run the INSERT query
    $insert = mysql_query
    ("
    INSERT INTO cmsdf_users(username,user_email)
    VALUES (NULL,'".$user."','".$user_email."')
    "); 


     // Check to make sure this particular INSERT worked
     if (!mysql_insert_id())
     {
          echo "ERROR: there was a problem inserting data.";
     }
}

// Close the connection
print mysql_close($con);

?>
```

But doesn't seem to work it gives the following error

```
Resource id #11SELECT * FROM letnp_usersResource id #2Cprl.Rstadmin@vivahosting.co.ukERROR: there was a problem inserting data.1
```

Comment: This may not answer your question but: 1) Avoid plain text password at all cost, 2) [Stop using mysql_ functions](http://www.deprecatedphp.com/mysql)

Comment: Whats with all the `print`'s?

Comment: The `or die(mysql_error());` should be on the end of the next line, surely?

Comment: @njk the plain txt password will hopefully get md5 into the Dragonfly database.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone i was told to do this to test for errors

Comment: @Timm not sure as all this is new to me.

looks like the current error was added and is not clear above so please see error below

This is one of 7 

Resource id #11SELECT * FROM letnp_usersResource id #2Cprl.Rstadmin@vivahosting.co.ukERROR:there was a problem inserting data.1

Comment: Move the `or die(mysql_error())` onto the end of the next line so that line becomes `print $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());` (this is the line with comment '// Run the query')

Comment: ok i have done that so i now have 

// Select the records from the database
print $query = "SELECT * FROM letnp_users" 

or die(mysql_error());

// Run the query
print $result = mysql_query($query);

Comment: That's the same as before! You want `print $query = "SELECT * FROM letnp_users"; print $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());`, also, as @LawrenceCherone said, why are you `print`ing this?